# How to make content in html page to exceed the webpage horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I have some content in the body and what i need is, content should exceed the page without horizontal scrollbar. The body should cut on lift and right hand side as shown in the picture. The side regions should not be visible. How to do this? [image]

Comment: What you are doing? Are you going to try this in real world project? And also, you will have to use `overflow: hidden;` to hide your content, rest bounced over my head

Comment: @Mr.Alien: In my real project there r some images instead of this text. not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There's likely dozens of ways to achieve something like that. Without knowing more about your objectives, it's hard to say which is best (ie, why do you want to hide content?).

Here's one way:

CSS:

```
body {overflow: hidden;}
div.content {width: 140%; position: relative; left: -20%;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="content">all your page content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
<body>
    <div style="padding-bottom:20px; width:303px;">
             <div id="myContent" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; border-bottom:none;">
              Some ContentSome ContentSome ContentSome ContentSome ContentSome ContentSome ContentSome ContentSome ContentSome ContentSome ContentSome ContentSome Content
             </div> 
        </div>
</body>
```